# Android - How to reschedule a sync request when it failed

Tags: android, synchronization

After updating a record in the DB the `SyncAdapter` is fired to upload the change to the server.
However if the uploading fails, how do I tell the `SyncManager` to repeat the sync?
I tried setting `syncResult.fullSyncRequested = true` but nothing happens.
Do I have to `ContentResolver.requestSync()` from inside the `SyncAdapter`?

Comment: The sync will try again all on its own, using an exponential backoff algorithm

Answer (score 2):

Since you're saying your sync failed, I'm guessing you probably set some of the error indicating fields in your `SyncResult.stats`. Try clearing them.

I had the exact same problem with this code

```
syncResult.stats.numAuthExceptions++;
syncResult.fullSyncRequested = true;
AccountManager.get(getContext()).invalidateAuthToken(account.type, token);
return;
```

and removing the `numAuthExceptions++` made it reschedule immediately, as intended.

The docs say about `fullSyncRequested`:

> If set the SyncManager will request an immediate sync with the same Account and authority (but empty extras Bundle) as was used in the sync request.

However, looking at the [`SyncManager` source](http://osxr.org/android/source/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/SyncManager.java#2259) I think it actually complies to both the exponential backoff and the minimum delay specified. Not sure if this is a bug or if I just misunderstand the (somewhat sparse) documentation on syncing.

Answer (score 0):

What I have found is fullSyncRequested does not immediately schedule a resync but adheres to the backoff algorithm. Also if SyncResult#hasSoftError needs to return true it seems.